# Como puedo pasar un valor al VUE desde un link

Tags: laravel, json, vue.js, response

Necesito recoger el id de un registro y mostrarlo con VUE desde un JSON.

Archivo response:

```
class DetalleResource extends JsonResource {
    public function toArray($request) {
        return [
         'id' => $this->id,
         'titulo' => $this->titulo,
         'foto' => $this->foto,
         'descripcion' => $this->descripcion,
         'created_at' => (string)$this->created_at,
         'updated_at' => (string)$this->updated_at,
       ]; 
    }
}
```

Controlador:

```
class DetalleController extends Controller {
    function show ($id) {
        DetalleResource::withoutWrapping();
        return new DetalleResource(Noticia::find($id));
    }
}
```

Ruta en api.php:

```
Route::get('detalle/{id}', 'DetalleController@show');
```

Archivo vue:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        json: null,
    },
});
$.getJSON('/api/detalle/id.json', function (json) {
    app.json = json;
}.bind(this));
```

Lo llamo desde un link dentro de un bucle que muestra todas las noticias:

```
<div class="col content">
    <a href="noticia-detalle.html">
        <input type="hidden" v-value="item.id">
        <p>Detalle Noticia</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Pero en el archivo detalle.html me sale vacío, ¿Como puedo recoger el id de la noticia seleccionada?

```
<div id="app">
    <p class="title">{{ json.titulo }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Que se supone que te devuelva esta ruta: /api/detalle/id.json?????

Comment: ¿No deberías poner v-value="json.id" ?

Comment: La ruta /api/detalle/1, o 2, etc, efectivamente me devuleve la noticia seleccionada, pensaba que id.json serviria como variable, pero obviamente no devuelve nada.                                                           
(Javi Molla) Si, es que en realidad esta dentro de un bucle <div class="row" v-for="item in json">

Comment: Como dice @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas, ¿puede que estés llamando a la url '/api/detalle/id.json' no a '/api/detalle/1' ni '/api/detalle/2'?

Comment: Precisamente, no se como coger esa variable-> '/api/detalle/(variable id)' que la tiene que manda el <input type="hidden" v-value="item.id">. He probado con '/api/detalle/id' y '/api/detalle/' + id, pero nada parece funcionar.

Comment: Si puedes ponme tu sistema de directorios porque no acabo de entender como lo tienes estructurado. Al menos la parte de vue

Comment: Dentro de la carpeta public tengo la noticia-detalle.html y noticias.html, el vue dentro de una carpeta js en la misma carpeta public